# Parameters in a neural tensor network

Tags: neural-networks, parameterization, tensor

I am reading the paper of "Reasoning With Neural Tensor Networks for Knowledge Base Completion". I read it many times but I couldn't understand the parameters that are used especially the parameter U. they say that is one of the standard parameters of a basic neural net. I didn't get that, did I miss something or what?

[image: The parameter U is not clear at all I search everywhere it stand for what but I could found!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you shouldn't read into it too much. It's simply a dot product between relation specific weights and the entity pair embedding. You can also think of $U$ as being the sole parameters in the last layer of the network which has no activation, no bias, and one output.

Comment: So you are telling me that I can eliminate it when I will use this formula again?

Comment: @bttX what do you mean "eliminate it"

Comment: I mean just rewrite the formula again without it :)

Comment: @bttX no, you can't just ignore it, because $g$ is supposed to be a scalar, and the output of $f$ is a vector...

Comment: maybe i can. i saw same formula but without this _U_ like this [one](https://imgur.com/hOdOTFC)

Comment: @bttX sure, if you want a vector output then you don't need $U$.